# Counting by grouping

Tags: probability, combinatorics

In general could someone explain the difference between the following two approaches?

Say we have $n$ objects split into $r$ groups of sizes $n_1, \ldots n_r$. What is the difference between

$$\frac{n!}{n_1!\cdots n_r!}$$ and $$r!n_1!\cdots n_r!.$$

When is each valid? The first says we have split these objects up by first choosing $n_1$ of them and then $n_2$, etc. The second says we have these groups, we can shuffle them internally ($n_k!$) and we can shuffle the whole groups ($r!$)$. What is the difference?

Example 1:
Natalie is taking a multiple choice exam with 20 questions, each of which has four
options: A, B, C, and D. There are $4^{20}$ possible ways she can choose one answer for
each question. How many of these ways involve exactly 5 questions answered A, 5
questions answered B, 5 questions answered C and 5 questions answered D?

So I'm confused here if this is just

$$\frac{20!}{5!^4}$$ since we are splitting it up into 4 groups of $5$, or if it is actually

$$4!5!^4$$ since we have 4 groups of 5.

Example 2: 8 objects can be arranged in how many ways so that two of them, $A$ and $B$ are together.

is this $8!/2!$? Since we have 6 groups of 1 and a group of 2? or is it $2*7!$?

For further discussion see the comments below.

Comment: Perhaps different questions have different answers, such as your first being $\frac{20!}{5!^4}$ and second $2\times7!$

Comment: @Henry Yes, but my question is when is each method applicable and what exactly is each one saying that makes them different?

Comment: @Henry In particular I do not see the underlying fundamental difference between the two examples, and thus do not understand why different methods are used, and also why these methods give different answers to begin with.

Answer (score 3):

This is long, but a thorough reading should clear any confusion. The first formula 
$$\frac{n!}{n_1!\cdots n_r!}$$
Gives every single ordering of $n$ elements split into $r$ different groups of identical objects with $n_i$ identical objects in the $i$'th group. An example that may give some insight is ordering the letters $AAABC$. Here there would be $5!$ ways of arranging  the elements, except that there are $3$ $A$'s. In any arrangement of $AAABC$, these three $A$'s could be arranged in any of $3!$ different (but identical from the problem's standpoint) orders $$A_1A_2A_3,A_1A_3A_2,A_2A_1A_3,A_2A_3A_1,A_3A_1A_2,A_3A_2A_1$$

The $5!$ accounts for them all. We are not interested in this distinction between $A_1$, $A_2$ and $A_3$ however, so we divide out the $3!$ in order to get the number of different arrangements. We can make the same argument for the $B$ and $C$, dividing out a $1!$, but this doesn't really matter for obvious reasons. Using all of these, however, we can get that the number of ways to arrange $AAABC$ is
$$\frac{5!}{(3!)(1!)(1!)}=20$$
In your first example, you are trying to find the number of ways to arrange $AAAAABBBBBCCCCCDDDDD$, so you get 
$$\frac{20!}{(5!)^4}$$
In your second example, $A$ and $B$ are distinct and stick together, two things wholly unaccounted for by this formula, so it does not apply.

Now for the second formula. This formula describes a sort of shuffling, as you mention, but this shuffling is a very distinctive kind of shuffling. It describes $r$ groups, each with $n_r$ distinct objects. The groups stay together in this shuffling, so after we multiply the shufflings of each individual group, which is $n_1! \cdots n_r!$, and then we shuffle the order of the groups themselves, thus multiplying by another $r!$ to get $$r!n_1!\cdots n_r!$$

In your first example this formula does not apply as there are no groups that are separate from each other. We are trying to find all orderings of $AAAAABBBBBCCCCCDDDDD$, not finding orderings of four groups $AAAAA$, $BBBBB$, $CCCCC$ and $DDDDD$. First off, then we would have streaks of 5 of the same answer in a row. Secondly, these answers are not even distinct, so we can't even begin to apply the second formula.

In your second example, we are ordering $ABCDEFGH$, but we are told $A$ and $B$ are in a group, that is, they cannot be separated. Thus we have seven groups, one is $AB$, and the others are $C$, $D$, $E$, $F$, $G$ and $H$. All letters are distinct here so we can use our second formula, multiplying the number of arrangements of each individual group $(2! (1!)^7)$ by the number of ways of arranging the groups themselves $7!$, so we have $2 \cdot 7!$.